# Need to Narrow Query Results that appear in Subform then Select and show Average

Tags: database, ms-access, subquery, keyword-search

I Need to Narrow my Query Results (that appear in Subform) using an additional keyword search box. Then with those results, I need to be able to choose the records needed and show the calculated average of the records selected in the main search form.

I have made an instant keyword search query (search as you type to display in real time) and built a form with a Query subform to display the results. Also tried to repeat the same part of the code for the 2nd search keyword search box (titled "Filter") but it keeps requery based on the orginal data, instead of the results data.

Code from the Query below....

```
SELECT [Combined Source Data].*
FROM [Combined Source Data]
WHERE ((([Source] & [Class Code] & [Classification Title] & [Department/Division]) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchForm]![Search].[Text] & "*" And ([Source] & [Class Code] & [Classification Title] & [Department/Division]) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchForm]![FILTER].[Text] & "*"));
```

Code from the unbound search boxes, which has a change on event procedure....

```
Private Sub Filter_Change()
DoCmd.Requery "SearchQuery subform"
End Sub

Private Sub Search_Change()
DoCmd.Requery "SearchQuery subform"
End Sub
```

The second Keyword search should filter the results, but it does not. Please help ---been trying to crack this for DAYS...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When a reference to an Access component is embedded in an SQL statement, any errors that occur from such references are often suppressed.  That's the case with the given SQL query, since the `Textbox.Text` property is not accessible unless the control has focus.  If you attempt to reference the control from other VBA code, for example

```
Private Sub OtherField_GotFocus()
   Debug.Print "Search: " & Me.Search.Text
End Sub
```

you should get an error

> Error 2185:  You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus.

And since you reference two separate Textbox controls in the same way, both cannot have focus at the same time, so there will always be one or the other values not properly included in the query. The question text says that

> ... it keeps requery based on the orginal data, instead of the results data.

but I suspect that the query resolves to something like `... Like "*search_term*" and ... Like "**"` or `... Like "**" and ... Like "**"` depending on what control has focus, so one side of the AND operator is always True.

---

Despite the error message's generality, the `Value` property can be referenced without the control having focus (and thus inside an SQL statement).  The drawback in your case is that it is not immediately updated with every new keystroke and so also not with every firing of the `Change` event.  You'll need to devise a different way to implement the "instant" aspect of the Textboxes, or you'll have to adopt another method like a traditional Search button.

Comment: I see, how would I turn this into a traditional search button. I am okay with having a button to fire the change event... just not familiar in how to do so with the multiple keywords boxes. how would I change the code to do so?

Comment: That really should be another Stackoverflow question... but only if you have problems after separately researching and testing how to add a button.  Hint:  Put a button on a form, then add code to the Click event, following a similar pattern to how you added code to the Textbox Change event.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out.